# Endogeneity Analysis without the access of raw data?

Tags: regression, least-squares, covariance, copula, endogeneity

I currently have the correlation/covariance matrix for a set of variables, as well as the output from a regression analysis, but lack access to the underlying raw dataset. Given these constraints, would it be feasible to conduct a comprehensive analysis of endogeneity? If so, I would greatly appreciate guidance on methodologies or statistical techniques that could be employed to investigate the presence of endogeneity under these circumstances.

Thanks,

Harshavardhana

Comment: Exactly what "output from a regression analysis" do you have?  If you don't have detailed information about the residuals, you cannot reasonably hope to perform any such analysis.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I only possess the regression equation of the form y = constant + ax1 + bx2, and so on, without any information on the distribution of the residuals. I recall the example of Anscombe's quartet, which illustrates that without access to the original data and an understanding of the underlying distribution of the data, it is not feasible to conduct a thorough analysis. Please correct me if my understanding is not accurate.

Comment: Using the Cholesky decomposition to simulate data from a random distribution can create an approximately similar correlation matrix. However, potential issues arise because this method fabricates data based on the assumption of a standard normal distribution for all features. Please let me know if this is the proper way to continue